# how to make object in array to be array

Tags: javascript

```
let origin = "[{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':3, 'b':4}, {'a':5, 'b':6}]"

let output = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':3, 'b':4}, {'a':5, 'b':6}]
```

How to make origin to be output as a array

Comment: Can you not modify `origin` to be valid JSON? Because that will simplify things immensely.

Comment: I am not familiar with JSON. Do you mean to be like this "{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':3, 'b':4}, {'a':5, 'b':6}"?

Comment: `"[{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':3, 'b':4}, {'a':5, 'b':6}]"` -> `'[{"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":3, "b":4}, {"a":5, "b":6}]'` the keys have to be in double quotes.

Comment: JSON needs double quotes around keys and string values

Comment: If it is double quotes, I can use `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: [Yes](https://jsbin.com/xijabod/edit?js,console)